# Normalization of attributes in test set for a neural network

Tags: neural-networks, normalization

I have built a neural network classification model and each attribute is z-normalized when building the model by the following X=(x-training set sample mean)/training set sample deviation.

If I now have new instances that I want to classify, how should I normalize the row data? Doing the same transformation by using the training set sample mean and sample deviation? What is the best practices in handling this type of issue?

Answer (score 1):

As you said. Basically, the zscores are a transformation with parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ which have to be estimated from the training data.